# checking record before inserting in sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

i am adding records using INSERT statement. now i want to check whether the email has already been registered or already present in the records..if it is already present just give an error otherwise insert a new record.. this is how iam doing it... but the select query is not running...and still adding records without checking.please check my code and please suggest a solution. Thanks :) here is my code for

```
 manage-users.php
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php
if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php include("includes/pre-header.php");?>


<title>Admdin Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/nav.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent">

<div class="span-24 last">
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="">Home</a> >
    <a href="">Manage Users</a> >
    Add New
</div>
</div>
<?php include("includes/manage-users-aside.php"); ?>
<div class="span-18 last">
<h2 class="alt">Add New</h2>
<?php
if (isset($_GET["status"]))
{
if($_GET["status"]==1)
{
?>
<div class="success">
<?php
echo("<strong>User Has Been Added Successfully!</strong>");
?>
</div>
<?php
}
 if($_GET["status"]==2)
{
?>
<div class="success">
<?php
 echo("<strong>User Has Been Edited Successfully!</strong>");
?>
</div>
<?php
}
} 
 if($_GET["status"]==3)
{
echo ("<strong>This Account Already Exixts!. Please add a New One!</strong>");
}
?>
<form method="post" id="form" action="manage-users-action.php">
<label for="email">Email/Username:</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
<label for="password">Password:</label><input id="password" type="password" name="password"  value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label><input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
<label for="lastname">Last Name:</label><input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname"    value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
<label>Type:</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" />Student <br /> <br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" />Teacher<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");

 }
?>
```

this is      manage-users-action.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php
$fname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lname=$_POST['lastname'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pwd=$_POST['password'];
$recoverykey=md5(time());
$encpwd=md5($pwd);
$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$result= mysql_query("SELECT FROM accounts WHERE (email='".$email."')");
if(!$result){
$sql=("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES   (NULL,'".$email."','".$encpwd."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$type."','".$recoverykey."')"    );
}
else
{
 header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=3");
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
    {
        header("Location:manage-users.php?status=1");
    }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why check first? If the database has a unique constraint on that column, try the insert, if a duplicate index error is returned, handle it in code.  You save a trip to the DB.

Comment: @xQBert, make than an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: @AlainCollins I would but it doesn't address the specific question.  Which is why I left it as a comment.  Answers should address the specific question.  I do in a round about way; but I don't think it's answerworthy unless the question changes to something like "What's the best way to handle checking for duplicates when inserting records" (my best way would be to have a stored procedure do the work and have the inline SQL removed as it opens the door to SQL injection.)  I was just trying to get the author to think about alternatives.

Comment: You checked his code and offered a solution as he requested.  That's an answer to me, SO-nazis be damned.  OK, I'll just upvote your comment then.  Sigh.

Comment: @Riu, since you think it's the `SELECT` that's "not running", have you run the _exact_ `SELECT` statement by hand?

Comment: xQbert dear its not unique column..coz im using id column as unique for some reasons..i just dont want user to add same email adress again  so whenevr user forgets the password the i could mail tht specific person on that specific email :)
anyways thanx for ur help

Comment: You can have two (or more) unique indexes in the database. Not strongly receommended, but for purposes like this, it's ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (!$result) {
```

try

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 )
```

Your query ***always*** returns a result - even when there is no record in the DB - that's why your condition never worked.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have several errors in the flow. Zolthan is right, but you'd still end up with two entries in the database as your code would carry on executing after the "header". Always `exit();` after a 'header location` call.

You also need to validate / make safe your data (otherwise $retval will be false, and it'll error if you followed Zoltan to the letter.)

Fixing things up :

```
// Validate you have an valid email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=ErrorInSQL");    // Note: location should take a full URL. This works in all browsers I know of, but is not strictly correct.
     exit();  // Critical - otherwise you script will continue to run.
}

// Than sanatize your data. Use PDO or mysql; for for now I'll use your code
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
// Repeat for the other fields

$result= mysql_query("SELECT FROM accounts WHERE (email='".$email."')"); 
if (!$result) { 
     header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=ErrorInSQL");    // Note: location should take a full URL. This works in all browsers I know of, but is not strictly correct.
     exit();  // Critical - otherwise you script will continue to run.
} else (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )  
     header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=NotUniqueURL");
     exit();  // Critical - again.
}

// As we're here, we can now do thq SQL as you have
// Remmber mysql_real_escape_string on all variables (or use PDO / mysqli prepared statements)
$sql=("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES   (NULL,'".$email."','".$encpwd."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$type."','".$recoverykey."')"    ); 
if (mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    header("Location:manage-users.php?status=1"); 
    exit();   // ;)
} else {
    header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=ErrorInSQL");
    exit();   // ;)
}
```

But, as suggested by xQbert, your best approach is in one query.

Create a "unique" index in the database on the field "email".

```
// Validate you have an valid email
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=ErrorInSQL");    // Note: location should take a full URL. This works in all browsers I know of, but is not strictly correct.
     exit();  // Critical - otherwise you script will continue to run.
}

// Than sanatize your data. Use PDO or mysql; for for now I'll use your code
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
// Repeat for the other fields

// Dive traight into the SQL
// Remmber mysql_real_escape_string on all variables (or use PDO / mysqli prepared statements)
$sql=("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES   (NULL,'".$email."','".$encpwd."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$type."','".$recoverykey."')"    ); 
if (mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    header("Location:manage-users.php?status=1"); 
    exit();   // ;)
} else {
    // This could error because it is in use, or you have error in your sql. So debug with mysql_error() initially to get your SQL correct, then when you're sure that is right, assume any error is duplicate e-mail. You could alsocheck with with mysql error codes to be extra safe.  
    header("Location: manage-uesrs.php?status=AlreadyInUse");
    exit();   // ;)
}
```